# How can I show the selected item centred of the pivot header in UWP?

Tags: win-universal-app

By default the item selected from the pivot header appears on the left side. This behavior can be changed so that it appears centered or right side?
I have a list of 20 items and therefore they don't appear all at the pivot header. So it is visually more appealing if the selected item appears centered on the screen.

Currently is working like the follow image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLFzW.png)

I would like it will work like the follow image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mjKb.png)

Comment: I think that you can do this, in my opinion if better use hamburger menu if you have a lot of items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need, skip to 26:30.

> https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-for-windows-10-layout-14328?l=cEHXB74sB_4304819052

There's a lot to it, but you can do it using the Pivot control.

Best of luck.

Comment: This example works fine, but only when the number of pivots is small and all fit on the screen. But if I have many pivots where the header items don't fit on the screen, the selected header item always appears on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

please check this post 
https://blog.hompus.nl/2015/09/04/responsive-pivot-headers-in-universal-windows-platform-apps/

you need to modify HorizontalContentAllignment property to center the content

Here is some example modifying the style with setters

Comment: This example works fine, but only when the number of pivots is small and all fit on the screen. But if I have many pivots where the header items don't fit on the screen, the selected header item always appears on the left side.

Comment: well In the guidelines of Windows Phone 8/8.1 I remember it's bad practice to use the pivot control to show more than 4 pivot items (performance issues) maybe you can use another approach like Hamburguer menu.